# Cannot extend partition beyond 2TB on AWS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, amazon-ec2

```
a@b:~$ sudo growpart -v /dev/xvda 1
update-partition set to true
resizing 1 on /dev/xvda using resize_sfdisk_dos
6291456000 sectors of 512. total size=3221225472000 bytes
WARN: disk is larger than 2TB. additional space will go unused.
## sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/xvda
label: dos
label-id: 0x965243d6
device: /dev/xvda
unit: sectors

/dev/xvda1 : start=        2048, size=  4294965247, type=83, bootable
max_end=4294967296 tot=6291456000 pt_end=4294967295 pt_start=2048 pt_size=4294965247
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by 1 [fudge=2048]


a@b:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda         202:0    0    3T  0 disk
└─xvda1      202:1    0    2T  0 part /
xvde         202:240  0   64G  0 disk
```

Trying to extend a 2TB partition to 3TB. Is the partition limited to 2TB?

Comment: Is the disk formatted as `mbr`or `gpt`?

Comment: Its mbr and i see a 2TB constraint for mbr here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_constraints.html

Comment: That's the issue. I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your drive is formatted as `MBR`.

For drives larger than 2TB, they need to be partitioned as `GPT` as `MBR` is limited to 2TB regardless of the OS.

Comment: so I noticed this. and switched from the default ubuntu AMI (which somehow in 2020 still uses MBR) to debian which is GPT. I was also unable to grow the partition. Any advice?

Comment: @MikeH-R I had a similar situation with Amazon Linux 2. Upgrading growpart solved the problem. Somehow the version shipped with the AMI was capped at 2 TB.

Comment: @Ihor, some tip how to updagrade growpart?

Comment: @Lucas on Amazon Linux ```yum update cloud-utils-growpart```

Comment: Also on Ubuntu, upgrading growpart to latest version solved the problem of enlarging over 2 TB a GPT partition

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to all this like I was, first you need to move from MBR to GPT. you can use the gdisk utility

```
# run gdisk /deev/device_name e.g.  nvme2n1 
gdisk /dev/nvme2n1
```

**NB:** Make sure you have a backup of your disk because you could mess up your data if you are not careful.

The above command will ask you to enter `?` for the help menu. Type then then type `w` to write the new GUID partition table (GPT) to  your drive. Select `y` at the prompt.  It will the go on to write the GPT on the drive.

After this you need to run parted to actually extend the disk.

```
# run parted /dev/device_name e.g
parted /dev/nvme2n1
```

Again this will ask you to type `help` if you need to get a list of commands.  Type `help` to get familiar with parted. The command you need to resize the partition is `resizepart` . It will ask you the partition number and the end size of the partition.  Enter those accordingly. You should then be able to work with the partition the way you would have done if you used `growpart` .

Comment: thanks for this! How would I do the `resizepart` stuff example? Your gdisk and parted examples are helpful, but for `resizepart` I'm not sure.