# How can I clone from 1TB MBR ssd to 4TB GPT ssd?

Tags: ssd, gpt, mbr, resize2fs, growpart

I have a raspberry pi with a 1TB hard drive. I managed to fill it up, so I purchased a new 4TB hard drive to replace it.

I then used software called "Macurim Reflect" to clone the previous 1TB ssd and all it's data onto the new 4TB hard drive. I then ran the following linux commands to make the pi aware of the resize:

```
sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

This worked well, but only resized the system to 2TB. I then discovered that 2TB is a limitation for drives formatted as `MBR`, and that `GPT` formatting is required for larger drives (see [Cannot extend partition beyond 2TB on AWS Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429507/cannot-extend-partition-beyond-2tb-on-aws-ubuntu))

**NOTE: I do not know what the heck MBR or GPT mean at all beyond the sentence above**

I want to enjoy the full size of the 4TB drive, but I do not want to lose any of the 1TB of data currently on it.

I tried running this:

```
umbrel@umbrel:~ $ sudo gdisk /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for umbrel:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): ?
b   back up GPT data to a file
c   change a partition's name
d   delete a partition
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   list known partition types
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
r   recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s   sort partitions
t   change a partition's type code
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): ^C
```

However, I got nervous at the warning `THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING PARTITIONS` and killed the process.

What should I do? What specific commands can I run to enjoy the full 4TB storage capacity without losing anything?

---

Edit: `fdisk -l /dev/sda` output:

```
umbrel@umbrel:~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for umbrel:
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: 500SSD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 627B1CC3-E53B-4D77-85C7-A111816F4628

Device     Start        End    Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 4294967295 4294965248   2T Linux filesystem
```

Comment: It would be easier to first create a GPT partition table, and then copy the data onto the disk. Cloning then extending can be done, but it's harder and riskier. What's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` ?

Comment: `gdisk /dev/sda1` is definitely wrong: you'd be creating partitions inside the existing MBR partitions, and no software would understand that. It should be `gdisk /dev/sda` and you should see something about MBR being present under “Partition table scan”.

Comment: More info on gpt than you may want: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ I use gparted from live installer. You can also use gparted but must change device label or default partitioning first.
With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.  Do you want one very large partition which may require another large drive for backup or a few smaller partitions? But you need to plan use & backup before partitioning.

Comment: I'm quickly learning that I'm a bit over my head. Is there any guides on migrating from MBR ssd to GPT ssd, enjoying the upgraded storage capacity without losing data? I am feeling a bit overwhelmed with the new concepts and I just want it to work.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I added the `fdisk -l /dev/sda` output to the question

Answer (score 0):

1.) Take your 4TB disk and add it to your linux. I assume you have now two HDD in your computer. /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

2.) fdisk /dev/sdb <= This should be your 4TB disk

3.) g   create a new empty GPT partition table

Fine. You have gpt disk now. But this is just Disklabe type, this is not a partition. You need to partitioning your disk now.

[image]

4.) n   add a new partition

5.) press Enters

[image]

But this is not enough. If you boot in BIOS style your OS stores the MBR on beginning of your old disk. This will not work on GPT disks. You should change the booting method to UEFI. But if you change the booting method you need to modify the GRUB.

If you decide to keep the BIOS boot please follow the instructions below:

There is an easy way to keep the BIOS boot method. Before you would created one large partition on your 4TB disk, create a little one. It should be bigger than 1MB.
And change its type to 'BIOS boot'.

If you're ready create an additional partition for your data.

Now you should have two partitions on your **GPT labelled disk**.

a.) 100MB BIOS boot partition as the first partition on your 4TB disk.

b.) 3999GB Linux partition as the second partition on your 4TB disk.

[image]

6.) Do not forget to press 'w' if you are good with the configuration.

These are just partitions. You need to create filesystem at least on your Linux partition.

```
$ sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb2
meta-data=/dev/sdb2              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=124607 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1    bigtime=0 inobtcount=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=498427, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
Discarding blocks...Done.
```

And you still not finished. Because the BIOS boot partition is empty on your new disk. So you need to repair it.

1.) Copy your entire old disk data to the new disk

```
$ mkdir /mnt/4TB
$ cp -av /* /mnt/4TB
```

1.) This is an [ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/).

2.) Boot from this disk and follow the instructions.

If you did everything well your GRUB will be fixed and you will be able to boot with your old OS from your new disk without data loss.